# Is GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullUp and GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullDown Supported?

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, windows-10-iot-core

When writing a Windows Universal App to run on a Raspberry Pi 2 with Windows 10 IoT I would like to have my input pin as a PullDown input.  The GpioPinDriveMode enumeration includes input pullup and input pulldown as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.devices.gpio.gpiopindrivemode.aspx).  My concern is that the Visual Studio 2015 intellisense is showing a "not supported" tool tip when using the pullup or pulldown enumeration.  Is it in fact not supported ?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is yes - but you can also always verify this in your code as well.

E.g., in C#:

> if (buttonPin.IsDriveModeSupported(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullUp))
>
> > blah, blah, blah

HTH.